# FFMPEG : image width stretched

Tags: ffmpeg

I try to add an image to a video between two times like this :

'`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image.jpg -filter_complex "[1]scale=500:500:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease[ovrl], [0][ovrl]overlay=0:0:enable=\'between(t,0,30)\'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy video_with_overlay.mp4`'

The video with image is succefully created but the image width is stretched just like the image adopted the video aspect ratio.

How can I keep the same image dimmensions?

**Edit :**
Inputs information :

**IMAGE**

```
ct_ratio -of json=c=1 input.jpg
    {
        "programs": [
    
        ],
        "streams": [
            { "width": 500, "height": 500, "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1", "display_aspect_ratio": "5:3" }
        ]
    }
```

**VIDEO**

```
ct_ratio -of json=c=1 video.mp4
{
    "programs": [

    ],
    "streams": [
        { "width": 960, "height": 720, "sample_aspect_ratio": "4:3", "display_aspect_ratio": "16:9" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: There is some missing information that is difficult to guess. Please use FFprobe as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65091550/4926757) for getting the missing information, and add it to your post: `ffprobe -hide_banner -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height,sample_aspect_ratio,display_aspect_ratio -of json=c=1 video.mp4` and for the image: `ffprobe -hide_banner -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height,sample_aspect_ratio,display_aspect_ratio -of json=c=1 image.jpg`. Will you consider scaling (resizing) `video.mp4` (in the process)?

Comment: Image :
Input #0, image2, from 'input.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6575 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Progressive), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 500x500 [SAR 1:1 DAR 5:3], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc.

FOR VIDEO : Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 960x720 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9], 801 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tb

Comment: It doesn't look like output of FFprobe that I asked for... Please add the information to your question. And... you didn't answer my last question.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Sorry, but I can't reproduce the issue. I am unable to create a JPEG image with SAR="1:1" and DAR="5:3". When using FFmpeg: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=512x512:rate=1:duration=1 -vf "setdar=5/3" image.jpg` the SAR and the DAR of `image.jpg` are equal.

Comment: Why you have deleted the answer?

Comment: I deleted the answer because it makes no sense. Can you share `image.jpg` (add it to your question)?

Comment: It no matters what SAR/DAR the image has, the issue remains the same for any image.

Comment: So upload any 500x500 image... You may reproduce the issue using synthetic video: Create  `video.mp4` with 960x720 with SAR=4:3:  `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=960x720:rate=1:duration=10 -vf "setsar=4/3" video.mp4`.  Create `image.jpg` 500x500: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=500x500:rate=1:duration=1 image.jpg`.  Overlay the image, and show that the image is stretched.

Comment: I solved the problem by your solution 1, and applied the same thing for marginX because  its been changed just like the width.

Comment: Great!!! (`marginX` is out of context, I guess you had to adjust the margin argument).

Comment: I have a placeholder inside the video for the image, and margin x is not accurate and should be multiplied by 3/4 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877243/why-ffmpeg-print-sar-instead-of-par) (Sample Aspect Ratio) of the input video is 4:3.
The resolution of the video is 960x720, and **the video player stretches the video** horizontally (say to 1280x720) - the aspect ratio of the displayed video is 16:9.

The SAR property is passed from the input to the output, so the overlaid image (with SAR 1:1) is stretched horizontally (by the video player) in a factor of 4/3.

---

First solution:
Scale the horizontal size of the overlaid image by `3/4` (and drop `force_original_aspect_ratio`):

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image.jpg -filter_complex "[1]scale=(500*3/4):500[ovrl];[0][ovrl]overlay=0:0:enable=\'between(t\,0\,30)\'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy video_with_overlay.mp4`

The solution assumes that `image.jpg` is squared, and that the SAR of the video in known to be 4:3.

---

Second solution:
Scale the input video horizontally by `4/3`, and set the SAR to `1:1` using `setsar` filter:

Scale the width by `sar` and set the SAR to 1:1: `[0]scale=w=in_w*sar:h=in_h,setsar=1[vid]`

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image.jpg -filter_complex "[0]scale=w=in_w*sar:h=in_h,setsar=1[vid]; [1]scale=500:500:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease[ovrl];[vid][ovrl]overlay=0:0:enable=\'between(t\,0\,30)\'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy video_with_overlay.mp4`

---

The second solution is probably better, but the file size may be a bit larger (and the resolution of the output video is going to be larger then the input video).

Comment: I have edited my question, but I don't have control of images , should I modify image sample aspect ratio before adding it to the video?